# how to find out of two points which one is closest to a set of points?

Tags: algorithm, coordinates, distance

how to find out of two points which one is closest to a set of points?

Suppose I have two points (x1,y1) and (x2,y2), I want to know which one is closer to a Set of points p1, p2, p3, p4.

Is there any algorithm for this??

Number of input points and the number of points in the Set are not fixed

We can have n number of inputs as well as n number of points in Set.

Comment: Define what is `сloser to a Set of points` clearly, mathematically

Comment: can the set be preprocessed offline (e.g, using a spatial index structure)?

Comment: @SaiBot: as the minimum distances depends on the complete set, it must be known before starting the queries.

Comment: @YvesDaoust my question was meant to clarify if the set of points can be preprocessed (e.g., with a KD Tree like you suggested) without affecting the query time. For example if there are two input points and the set of points is large (n) then if preprocessing is possible the query time will be O(log n) otherwise O(n)

Comment: @MBo,  What I am trying to convey is I have some reference points (Set of points) and I have some Target Points (Input Points). I want to know which one can be considered as the closest one to all the Reference Points (Set Of Points). I am basically trying this on Web Page Elements

Answer (score 1):

Construct a kD-tree on the Set points. This can be done in time Ns Log Ns.

Then for every Input point, find the nearest neighbor. This takes Ni Log Ns time. And finally, find the shortest distance in Ni comparisons.

Total time, (Ns + Ni) Log Ns. This is to be compared to brute force, taking Ns.Ni. For small Ni, brute force is preferable.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on how you define being “closest to a set of points”.

One super fast criterion could be “having the minimum sum of square distances to a set of points” (square distances are used, e.g., in curve fitting, so nothing strange here).

Using this criterion, you would just have to minimize `Σᵢ((xᵢ-x)²+(yᵢ-y)²)` , where `i` is the index over the set.